# In Android, how to execute a service as a different user?

Tags: android

For example, is there any way to define a service to run as 'system' UID or GID?

Or any way to add your app to the 'system' group?

Comment: I highly doubt it without building the whole system again.  Being able to make an app run as 'system' would obliterate all of the security checks in place.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Maybe we can help you if we knew your goal.

Comment: If you have a rooted phone, then you can run commands as root. But I believe it notifies the user first.

Comment: Well, playing with my wife's Droid X, I notice that some of the underlying hardware, namely the various leds 'brightness' file are set 0644 from Motorola, owned by system/system.  So my thought was that if I could access them directly, I could play with the LEDS (this is exactly how I do it on my EVO 4G - they are 0655)  I can't find anything in the Android Framework that correlates with the LEDs, so direct-access appears to be my only path.

Comment: Does this SO post address what you're looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122570/can-the-android-handset-led-be-maniuplated-without-using-a-notification-object

Comment: I'm afraid not, Chris.  I'll play with the NotificationManager, but for example I can pass values 0-5 to /sys/class/leds/wimax/brightness (0 - off, 1-5 - various modes) on my Evo4G, and allows me to utilize modes the LED can perform, that are not available to Android.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments on the question, this would create some security problems.  There is no way to run an app or service as "system".  (Barring bugs, of course.)

Comment: In other words, this would require rooting?