# How to make notification lights work in react-native on android?

Tags: android, react-native

I have a simple react-native camera app and I would like to make notification LED light up at the bottom of the phone, when app is recording. I was not able to find it on the official [docs](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html).

I removed unnecessary code (like the styles and  template) for ease of readability. My `index.android.js` is the following.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Image,
  StatusBar,
  StyleSheet,
  AppRegistry,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';

import Camera from 'react-native-camera';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    //...
});

export default class DashCam extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.camera = null;

    this.state = {
      camera: {
        aspect: Camera.constants.Aspect.fill,
        captureTarget: Camera.constants.CaptureTarget.cameraRoll,
        type: Camera.constants.Type.back,
        orientation: Camera.constants.Orientation.auto,
      },
      isRecording: false
    };
    this.switchCam = this.switchCam.bind(this);
    this.recording = this.recording.bind(this);
  }

  recording() {
    console.log(!this.state.isRecording);
    if(!this.state.isRecording) {
      if (this.camera) {
        this.camera.capture({mode: Camera.constants.CaptureMode.video})
            .then((data) => console.log(data))
            .catch(err => console.error(err));

        this.setState({ isRecording: true });
      }
      console.log('recording');
    } else {
      if (this.camera) {
        this.camera.stopCapture();
        this.setState({ isRecording: false });
      }
      console.log('stopped ');
    }
  }

  switchCam() {
    //...
  }

  get typeIcon() {
    //...
  }

  get camButton() {
    //...
  }

  render() {
    return (
        //...
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('DashCam', () => DashCam);
```

My `package.json` if you need it:

```
{
  "name": "DashCam",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "15.3.2",
    "react-native": "0.37.0",
    "react-native-camera": "git+https://github.com/lwansbrough/react-native-camera.git"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-react-native"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "17.0.2",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "1.9.0",
    "jest": "17.0.3",
    "jest-react-native": "17.0.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "15.3.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As you point out, this functionality is not included in RN, but the good thing is you can easily implement it yourself in Android code. Maybe something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122570/can-the-android-handset-led-be-manipulated-without-using-a-notification-object) can help you turn the LED on/off (by basically creating a dummy notification) and then you can build an Android module, which is actually fairly simple. You can have a look at the [Toast tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html) in the official docs.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll check it out! I'll have a jab at writing a module like you suggested.

Comment: I'm gonna add two more links: https://www.sitepoint.com/access-platform-apis-with-react-native-modules/
 http://www.41post.com/4706/programming/android-creating-a-two-color-led-notification