# Turn off notification light automatically expo

Tags: react-native, notifications, expo

How do i add led light **notifications** on my *react native* app that turn off when i press the notification

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you cannot do this with ReacNative alone.

The slightly longer answer is that you can control the LED light through Android code. You can read more in this question/answer: [How to make notification lights work in react-native on android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40683195/how-to-make-notification-lights-work-in-react-native-on-android)